# Cannot access VideoJS flash object

Tags: flash, video-streaming, video.js

I'm making radio live stream with [VideoJS](http://www.videojs.com/). I'm trying to use VideoJS without actual video.js javascript file — I'm using only the Flash part — video-js.swf file.

Here is my index.html (this is manually written code):

```
<object id="radio" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="/video-js.swf" width="0" height="0">
    <param name="allowNetworking" value="all">
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
    <param name="flashvars" value="autoplay=false&amp;preload=false&amp;loop=false&amp;muted=false&amp;rtmpConnection=rtmp://192.168.1.6/air/&amp;rtmpStream=stream">
    <param name="movie" value="/video-js.swf">
    <param name="wmode" value="opaque">
</object>
```

This is my RTMP server:

```
rtmp://192.168.1.6/air/stream
```

At this place everything is fine — if I write

```
autoplay=true
```

my page starts to play music... only in Chrome!

If I try to access Flash object with Javascript (after document load, of course):

```
setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('radio').vjs_pause();
}, 5000);
```

or

```
setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('radio').vjs_setProperty('volume', 0.25);
}, 5000);
```

or

```
any other ExternalInterface's methods from video-js.swf file
```

it also works... only in Chrome.

In FF, in IE, in Opera, all latest, I always get this errors:

```
document.getElementById('radio').vjs_play is not a function
document.getElementById('radio').vjs_pause is not a function
document.getElementById('radio').vjs_setProperty is not a function
```

So, what can be wrong with my simplest code? How can I access Flash object's methods like it is now in Chrome?

## JSFiddle:

```js
/*
    obviously, here in jsFiddle there will be an error in code below, because video-js.swf cannot load anything from rtmp://192.168.1.6/air — but on my local computer all this code works like a charm in Chrome, not in FF/IE/Opera
*/

setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('radio').vjs_play();
}, 5000);
```

```html
<object id="radio" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="/video-js.swf" width="0" height="0">
    <param name="allowNetworking" value="all">
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
    <param name="flashvars" value="autoplay=false&amp;preload=auto&amp;loop=false&amp;muted=false&amp;rtmpConnection=rtmp://192.168.1.6/air/&amp;rtmpStream=stream">
    <param name="movie" value="/video-js.swf">
    <param name="wmode" value="opaque">
</object>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is — you should always set *object* tag a **width** and a **height**:

```
<object ... width="100%" height="100%">...</object>
```

But, if you place this *object* above in some *div*, which has no sizes:

```
<div>
    <object ... width="100%" height="100%">...</object>
</div>
```

your Flash object will not work… because its size became 0x0 pixels.

(Well, it will work only in good browsers like Google Chrome).

I was using Angular's ng-transclude directive with a *div* block:

```
<div ng-transclude></div>
```

After transcluding, my HTML was:

```
<div ng-transclude="">
    <object ... width="100%" height="100%">...</object>
</div>
```

and of course its size was 0x0 pixels and Flash didn't worked.

Then I set 1x1 sizes and everything starts to work as expected:

```
<div ng-transclude="">
    <object ... width="1" height="1">...</object>
</div>
```

I've spent huge amount of hours, before came to the insight :)

Answer (score 1):

The swf isn't meant to be used on it's own, so I wouldn't recommend it.

But if you choose to still go that route, you can look at how the Flash tech uses the swf. Specifically, it [provides a ready function](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/a859575e62334d09ab2dc3532b0c86a3a34b1c0f/src/js/media/flash.js#L40) for the swf to call when the API methods are available.

Though that's not always stable so there's a also a [checkReady event](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/a859575e62334d09ab2dc3532b0c86a3a34b1c0f/src/js/media/flash.js#L300).

Comment: Hi, heff, I know you from VideoJS web site! :) I use only SWF because I really do not need 67 KB of JavaScript functionality I don't use — I just have 1 big button play/pause which should work exactly with Flash (because of stream support), etc., so I desided to use only SWF and its ExternalInterface's methods and everything works in Chrome 100% great.

Comment: I also explored all vjs.Flash.* part of your JavaScript source — well, is there some special trick when you dynamically create «object» tag and insert it into the DOM? As far as I can see (in vjs.Flash.embed + vjs.Flash.getEmbedCode) you just create «object»...«/object» string with all «params» and attributes and then just insert it in dynamically created div with innerHTML method… and this works in all browsers!

Comment: What I did is just modified your demo.html file so it can play the stream and then just copy/pasted resulting HTML «object» code in my index.html file… and I really don't get where is the trick why it works only in Chrome and not in all other browsers.

Comment: I honestly couldn't say why it's not working in your specific case in certain browsers. I haven't worked on that part of the code for a long time. But 67k isn't all that bad, especially when you consider the size of the video it's about to play. :)

Answer (score 0):

Also, I don't know how it is possible, but if you use Grunt's [connect-livereload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-livereload) it will break your  Flash object, because livereload is modifying your DOM.

So, I just have to remove lrSnippet from connect task's middleware array:

```
var LIVERELOAD_PORT = 35729;

var lrSnippet = require('connect-livereload')({
    'port': LIVERELOAD_PORT
});

// and then in config:

connect: {
    localhost: {
        options: {
            base: {
                path: 'app/assets',
                options: {
                    index: 'application.html'
                }
            },
            middleware: function(connect) {
                return [
                    lrSnippet, // remove it (well, if you are using Chrome, do not remove livereload, it will work fine in Chrome)

                    mountFolder(connect, 'tmp'),
                    mountFolder(connect, 'app/assets')
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```